# Get Percentiles per group in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to calculate percentiles for Bid/Ask prices for a large group of Bond ISINs. Specifically I have my data formatted like below:

| Securities | PxBid | PxAsk | PxMid | GroupID | Q1 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.598 | 114.198 | 113.898 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.684 | 114.152 | 113.918 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.878453 | 114.090701 | 113.984577 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.777 | 114.239 | 114.008 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.809 | 114.209 | 114.009 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.53 | 114.53 | 114.03 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.795 | 114.295 | 114.045 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 114.07 | 114.07 | 114.07 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 114.1 | 114.1 | 114.1 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A04967 | 114.105 | 114.185 | 114.145 | 1 | 113.7073 | 114.0221 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.355 | 100.355 | 100.355 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.257 | 100.457 | 100.357 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.28 | 100.435 | 100.358 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.284 | 100.434 | 100.359 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.275 | 100.443 | 100.359 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 98.86 | 101.86 | 100.36 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.311 | 100.411 | 100.361 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.313055 | 100.411003 | 100.362029 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.37 | 100.37 | 100.37 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.3748 | 100.3948 | 100.3848 | 2 | 100.2763 | 100.3445 |

I want to calculate the 25th and 75th percentile per ISIN, e.g. for the group as shown in the table above. I have tried using the below formula:

```
Q1 = PERCENTILEX.INC(
ALLSELECTED(CleansedBenchmark[Securities]),
CleansedBenchmark[PxBid],
0.25)
```

But that just gives me the same bid for each row:

| Securities | PxBid | PxAsk | PxMid | GroupID | Q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.598 | 114.198 | 113.898 | 1 | 113.598 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.684 | 114.152 | 113.918 | 1 | 113.684 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.878453 | 114.090701 | 113.984577 | 1 | 113.8785 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.777 | 114.239 | 114.008 | 1 | 113.777 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.809 | 114.209 | 114.009 | 1 | 113.809 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.53 | 114.53 | 114.03 | 1 | 113.53 |
| AT0000A04967 | 113.795 | 114.295 | 114.045 | 1 | 113.795 |
| AT0000A04967 | 114.07 | 114.07 | 114.07 | 1 | 114.07 |
| AT0000A04967 | 114.1 | 114.1 | 114.1 | 1 | 114.1 |
| AT0000A04967 | 114.105 | 114.185 | 114.145 | 1 | 114.105 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.355 | 100.355 | 100.355 | 2 | 100.355 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.257 | 100.457 | 100.357 | 2 | 100.257 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.28 | 100.435 | 100.358 | 2 | 100.28 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.284 | 100.434 | 100.359 | 2 | 100.284 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.275 | 100.443 | 100.359 | 2 | 100.275 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 98.86 | 101.86 | 100.36 | 2 | 98.86 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.311 | 100.411 | 100.361 | 2 | 100.311 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.313055 | 100.411003 | 100.362029 | 2 | 100.3131 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.37 | 100.37 | 100.37 | 2 | 100.37 |
| AT0000A0U3T4 | 100.3748 | 100.3948 | 100.3848 | 2 | 100.3748 |

I'm sure I am missing something silly here, so any help is appreciated!
Ideally I want this in the same table, but maybe it's more efficient to create a new table to store the results per ISIN, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a calculated column you're adding to a table, then use the following code.

```
Q1 = 
CALCULATE(
PERCENTILEX.INC( 
    CleansedBenchmark,
    CleansedBenchmark[PxBid],
    0.25)
, ALLEXCEPT(CleansedBenchmark, CleansedBenchmark[Securities]))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. If not too much trouble, can you explain how ALLEXCEPT works here? According to the docs this: Removes all context filters in the table except filters that have been applied to the specified columns.
As I don't impose any filters in my table, is this required?

Comment: Because you're in a table, there is an implicit row context (different from filter context). Your formula is evaluated one row at a time and the ALLEXCEPT removes this restriction so that the table is effectively split into chunks by the Securities column, The formula is still evaluated per row but now the formula can also see the rest of the rows it needs to in order to work properly.

Comment: Have a read here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-in-dax/